# How to represent equality constraint in JOptimizer?

Tags: java, linear-programming, joptimizer

```
//Objective function
    double[] c = new double[] { -1., -1. };

    //Inequalities constraints
    double[][] G = new double[][] {{4./3., -1}, {-1./2., 1.}, {-2., -1.}, {1./3., 1.}};
    double[] h = new double[] {2., 1./2., 2., 1./2.};

    //Bounds on variables
    double[] lb = new double[] {0 , 0};
    double[] ub = new double[] {10, 10};

    //optimization problem
    LPOptimizationRequest or = new LPOptimizationRequest();
    or.setC(c);
    or.setG(G);
    or.setH(h);
    or.setLb(lb);
    or.setUb(ub);
    or.setDumpProblem(true); 

    //optimization
    LPPrimalDualMethod opt = new LPPrimalDualMethod();

    opt.setLPOptimizationRequest(or);
    opt.optimize();
```

These code are copied from JOptimizer official document. However, it only shows how to use inequality constraints in linear programming in JOptimizer. I am wondering how to represent an equality constraints in JOptimizer? I know I can achieve this goal by defining multiple inequality constraints, say Ax < b and -Ax < -b are the same thing as Ax=b. But is there any direct way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the answer. It's quite easy. We just need to replace setG and setH with setA and setB.